# Login desde formulario PHP

Tags: php, login

Creé un login bastante sencillo, este login va a recibir una clave y usuario que esta en una base de datos, el problema es que a la hora de querer ingresar resutla este error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$consulta' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/u314584234/public_html/php/login.php on line 7

Este es el codigo PHP del login:

```
include 'cn.php';
$usuario = $_POST['txt_user'];
$clave = $_POST['pass_clave']

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `u314584234_rgstr`.`usuarios` WHERE users = '$usuarios' AND clave = '$clave'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $consulta);


$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if ($filas > 0) {
    header("location:menu-registro.html")
}
else{
    echo "Error en la autentificación";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Votando para cerrar como error tipográfico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te falta un punto y coma (;) en la instruccion:

```
$clave = $_POST['pass_clave']   <--- ¿Donde esta el ; ?
```

Recuerda que en PHP, al igual que muchos otros lenguajes de programacion (de aquellos crueles donde todo finaliza en punto y coma), tu puedes hacer facilmente algo como esto:

```
$variable = "Hola"
;
```

Y no pasaria nada, porque el "parseo" (parse en ingles), se realiza hasta encontrar el siguiente **;**, por lo tanto, lo que hace que toda la sentencia `$clave`, se tome hasta el final de la otra variable:

```
$clave = $_POST['pass_clave']

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `u314584234_rgstr`.`usuarios` WHERE users = '$usuarios' AND clave = '$clave'"; <--- Finalizaria hasta aqui la variable `$clave`
```

Y ello es lo que te causa el error.

Comment: Eres muy observador, gracias, ya he solucionado el error, saludos.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione, he hecho una pequeña explicacion, indicandote lo que ocurrio

Answer (score 1):

Trata poniendo comillas dobles para concatenar las variables en la cadena $consulta, quedando así:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `u314584234_rgstr`.`usuarios` WHERE users = '".$usuarios."' AND clave = '".$clave."'";
```

Comment: Realicé lo que me dijiste y aun persiste el error

Comment: Cuando recibes 'txt_user' en la 2da línea de código, lo llamas $usuario
 y en la consulta pones $usuarios

corrección:
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `u314584234_rgstr`.`usuarios` WHERE users = '".$usuario."' AND clave = '".$clave."'";